# Is there a way to align icons within the Spring Integration graph of Spring Tool Suite when in manual layout mode

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.6.3.CI-B2266066, Build Id: 201411050946, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)) with Spring Integration 4.1.0.

I have a Spring configuration XML file that includes the Spring Integration namespace.  When I go into the integration-graph tab and go into "manual layout" mode, I'd like to be able to select more than one icon/graphic and have the option to align the icons relative to each other.  For example, similar to how Visio or MS Word or other drawing tools give options like "align top", "align bottom", "align center", "align left", etc.

Is there perhaps a view or toolbar that provides that which I'm not seeing?

Comment: I don't think this is implemented somewhere, but I like the idea very much. Would be great if you could file an enhancement request here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I've logged this as https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3971